AWS IoT Core MQTT Connection Immediately Disconnected After Refining Policy
I’m working with AWS IoT Core and trying to connect an MQTT client (MQTT Explorer) with a specific policy. When I use a broad policy (such as iot:* on Resource: *), everything works perfectly, and the connection remains stable. However, when I apply a more restrictive policy, the connection is immediately disconnected.
Here’s the refined policy I’m using:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-3:*******:client/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-3:*******:topicfilter/lite/command/#"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-3:*******:topic/lite/data/#"
    }
  ]
}

Setup Details:
Region: eu-west-3 MQTT Client: MQTT Explorer Certificates: Root CA, device certificate, and private key are properly configured. Endpoint: .iot.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com Client ID: 1122CCDDEEFF
With this policy, I’m trying to:
Subscribe to: /lite/command/# Publish to: /lite/data/test As soon as I connect using MQTT Explorer, the connection is immediately disconnected. This issue does not occur when I use a broader policy like this:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

What I’ve Checked:
Certificates: Certificates are active and attached to the policy. Logs: IoT Core logs are enabled, but I don’t see any clear errors. Keepalive: Set to 60 seconds in MQTT Explorer. Other Clients: The same issue occurs when testing with Mosquitto. Topic Path: The topic /lite/command/# should match the policy definition. My Questions:
Why does the connection immediately disconnect when using the stricter policy? Are there specific nuances with wildcards (# vs *) or topic configurations in the policy that I need to address? How can I fix this issue so that the policy works without relying on overly broad permissions?
Thanks in advance for your help!
